# No logro que pygame.key.set_repeat() reconozca un tecla presionado seguido de presionar otra tecla

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

necesito crear un boton de pausa para un videojuego pero de tal forma que permita mantener presionado un boton mientras que se despausa, caso que `pygame.key.set_repeat()` no reconoce la tecla que se mantiene presionada en el event loop, aqui un ejemplo:

```py
import pygame as pg
import sys

pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 200))
pg.display.set_caption('Prueba')
pause = False
pg.key.set_repeat(1, 25)

while True:
    pg.time.Clock().tick(60)

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                pause = not pause
                if pause:
                    print('juego pausado')
                else:
                    print('juego des-pausado')
                    pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
                    if pressed[pg.K_RETURN]:
                        print('se sigue presionando RETURN')

            elif not pause:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print('Se presiono RETURN')

    if pause:
        continue
```

Como ven si mantienen presionado `RETURN` antes de despausar, en termina dara el mensaje de que el juego se des-pauso, añadiendo que `RETURN` sigue estando presionado, pero dejara de repetir el mensaje "Se presiono RETURN".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener en cuenta que [`pygame.key.set_repeat`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat) simplemente hace que una vez que una tecla es pulsada (evento `KEYDOWN`), se sigan generando eventos `KEYDOWN` mientras de forma continuada si esta permanece pulsada con un determinado delay entre ellos. Pero si se pulsa otra tecla mientras tanto, el ciclo se rompe y empieza con la nueva tecla pulsada ignoraando la anterior.

Si te fijas, cualquier tecla que pulses mientras mantienes <kbd>Enter</kbd> pulsado (no solo el espacio) causa que el evento `KEYDOWN` de `K_RETURN` deje de generarse.

Personalmente no me gusta demasiado el uso de `pygame.key.set_repeat`, puedes solucionar tu problema con solo modificar un poco la lógica de tu mainloop y haciendo uso de `pygame.key.get_pressed` pero en la raíz del ciclo:

```
import pygame as pg
import sys


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((400, 200))
pg.display.set_caption('Prueba')
pause = False
clock = pg.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(60)

    pressed = pg.key.get_pressed()
    return_pressed = pressed[pg.K_RETURN]

    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pg.K_SPACE:
                pause = not pause
                if pause:
                    print('juego pausado')
                else:
                    print('juego des-pausado')
                    if return_pressed:
                        print('se sigue presionando RETURN')
    if not pause:
        if return_pressed:
            print('Se presiono RETURN')
    else:
        continue
```

Esto permite también que mantener pulsado <kbd>Espacio</kbd> no esté constantemente alternando entre pausado y no pausado, lo cual es muy molesto y difícil de manejar ya que debes realizar una pulsación muy rápida de la tecla para que no pase de no pausado a pausado e inmediatamente a no pausado de nuevo....